# How to check document already exist in IBM Domino

Tags: lotus-domino

I'm working on create an agent to move cancelled documents to archive database, before copy to archive database, I want to check if the document is already existed in archive database. There are some documents' main fields are same in database, so I can't use this fields to check if it is the same one. Are there any way to check if the document is the same document in two databases? I found that for same document, some part of unid are same in two databases(for example: unid in source database: 613D530A7B107F468**52578E9001DCC89** unid in dest database: 85258289002735FB852**578E9001DCC89**), but I'm not sure if this is a correct flag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the unid of documents (if not tampered with) consists of a a part computed from the database replica ID and a converted timestamp for "created" it is not pure coincidence, that the "same" document has a similar unid.

But this is NOTHING you can rely on and depends on the way you create your documents in the archive.

If you did something like

```
Set docArchive = New NotesDocument( dbArchive )
Call doc.CopyAllItems( docArchive, True )
```

Then the unids would not have anything to do with each other.

If you use `doc.CopyToDatabase`, it will depend on the number of attempts and may result in

- same unid in target
- similar unid in target (first copy of document)
- totally different unid in target (subsequent copies)

To identify your document you have to have a "key" for finding it.

One way would be to use the SAME universalid:

```
Set docArchive = New NotesDocument( dbArchive )
Call doc.CopyAllItems( docArchive, True )
docArchive.Universalid = doc.Universalid
Call docArchive.Save()
```

Then you could check for existance like:

```vb
On Error Resume Next
Set docArchive = dbArchive.getDocumentByUnid( doc.UniversalID )
On error Goto 0
If Not docArchive is Nothing then 'EXISTS
    ....
End If
```

If you don't want to go with the universalid directly, you could compute a key or again use the universalid of the source document as key:

```vb
Set docArchive = doc.CopyToDatabase( dbArchive )
strArchiveKey = doc.Universalid
'or compose unique key from 3 individual fields:
strArchiveKey = doc.getItemvalue( "OneField" )(0) & "-" & doc.getItemvalue( "AnotherField" )(0) & "_" doc.getItemvalue( "YetAnotherField" )(0)
Call docArchive.ReplaceitemValue( "ArchiveKey", strArchiveKey  )
Call docArchive.Save(True, True, True)
```

And then find the archive document from a search or better from a GetDocumentByKey in a view sorted by ArchiveKey:

```vb
Set docArchive = db.Search( {ArchiveKey = "} & strArchiveKey & {"}, Nothing, 0).getFirstDocument()

Set docArchive = viwLkp.GetDocumentByKey( strArchiveKey )
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

For mail documents or meeting invitations you could use the $MessageID field as a unique item to refer to before archiving. I used this in the past for feeding a CRM database with customer correspondence. The message ID is unique even across several mail databases which helps to keep the clutter to a minimum.

So, something like this (not tested, have no designer client available atm) ...

```
'you should have the destination db and the current doc as an object already

dim searchFormula$
dim collDestination as NotesDocumentCollection
dim docDestination as NotesDocument

'of course you could use a lookup view in the destination
'database instead using the less performant db.search

searchFormula$ =|$MessageID="|+cstr(docCurrent.getItemValue("$MessageID")(0))+|"|
set collDestination = dbDestination.search(searchFormula$, Nothing,1)

if not collDestination is Nothing then
 'do nothing or return document already in target database
 'set docDestination = collDestination.getFirstDocument()
else 
  'copy only if doc in destination db not found
  set docDestination = docCurrent.copytoDatabase(dbDestination)
end if
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I'm strongly opposed to **any** archiving by agents. Archiving should be handled using the standard Notes archiving options and fields. Ideally, a document only exists in either the main or in the archive database. When a document has to be archived, just add a field ExpireDate with a correct date and archiving should do the rest (when activated). No need to move documents yourself.

Comment: Notes does provide a rich set of standard archiving options, but (please correct me if I'm wrong) I believe they apply only to mail databases. I would agree that if you don't have a need to be archiving to non-NSF storage, there's no point in implementing your own archiving agents - and if you do need to archive to non-NSF media there are probably regulatory issues involved and I think you'll be much better off with a 3rd party archiving product! But I see no indication that this question is referring to archiving mail messages. I think it's about archiving from a custom application database.

Comment: As far as I know, any Notes database allows all sorts of archiving. Maybe the presentation is less sexy than in a database based on a mail template, but archiving is there (type Alt-Enter and select Archive Settings...). And even better: it works.

Comment: I suppose there aren't many people left who know that it exists and works, but the special field called ExpireDate can be used to set the expire date of a document. The standard Archive Ciriteria called Default for Expired handles documents based on this field. One more advantage (again, afaik, but I'm less sure here) is the fact that the universal id of a document doesn't change while being archived.

Comment: You're right. I totally forgot about that. Probably because I never knew about the ExpireDate. If you build setting that field into your business logic - including any logic that's dependent on other documents so that you don't archive dependent documents out from under still-active documents, it can be a good solution.